# hadoop on cygwin - DemoWordCount

Tags: hadoop

i want to run this command on Cygwin after building the jar fil cloud9-1.4.14.jar

hadoop jar dist/cloud9-1.4.14.jar edu.umd.cloud9.example.simple.DemoWordCount -input data/bible+shakes.nopunc.gz -output wc -numReducers 1

but it's not working the error on cygwin said it's in the file hadoop-env.sh

What shall i do ?

Answer (score 0):

I would not try and run Hadoop in Cygwin in windows. Instead I would use the following virtual machine image which has hadoop all set up for you.

http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2012/08/hadoop-on-your-pc-clouderas-cdh4-virtual-machine/

There are many things you have to do to set up hadoop. It is very hard to figure out what you may not have done. Using the vm image will save you a lot of time.

If you really want Cygwin
http://en.wikisource.org/wiki/User:Fkorning/Code/Hadoop-on-Cygwin

Comment: and after i downloaded the VM where do i write the commandes ?

Comment: terminal is the real linux version of cygwin